# RecyclerView with previous and next page boundaries?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

With ViewPagers, having previous and next page slightly revealed can easily be accomplished with "setPageMargin". For example,

```
vp.setPageMargin(-200)
```

could possibly result in a UI like the following:

[image]

But how to accomplish this with RecyclerViews? The items have to be equally spread, and the current item should be centered.

To setup my RecyclerView to mimic a ViewPager, I took advantage of PagerSnapHelper()

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
RecyclerView rvHorizontal = findViewById(R.id.rv_horiz);
rvHorizontal.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvHorizontal);
// set adapter
mAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(context, mData);
rvHorizontal.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The PagerSnapHelper() allows me to scroll and have a page snap in place, however, how do I get page reveal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to accomplish this with RecyclerViews? The items have to be
>   equally spread, and the current item should be centered.

You can just set the width of `ViewHolder` item view to achieving this effect in `RecyclerView`.

And you should use `LinearSnapHelper` instead of `PagerSnapHelper`.

Comment: It's not that simple. To center the item on screen, and include equal spacing between items based on screen size, as well as page reveals cannot be done by just adjusting the width of your ViewHolder item view. I will continue trying and post proper answer.

Comment: Have not tried the LinearSnapHelper, let me try that out. You may be on to something. The issue I ran into with the PagerSnapHelper is screen 1. When I adjust the width, the first item is not centered in the screen. The spacing between items work. But starting off with your first item centered on screen I could not get to work because adjusting the spacing would shift the item position. But I will continue trying. I have this working with ViewPager right now.